# Función que modifique atributo "onclick"?

Tags: javascript, funciones, botón, function

esperando estén teniendo un buen día, necesito de vuestra ayuda.
Compartiré el código completo del ejercicio que intento resolver.
En esencia, son dos botones "+10" y "+5", que al ser presionados suman sin límites al "Total", el cual refleja de manera correcta la suma.
Adicionalmente, hay un botón "Clear" el cual vuelve todo a 0 y debajo de él, una imagen espejo a la opción seleccionada. Es una especie de recordatorio que solo muestra cual fue la última opción seleccionada.
Hasta ahi todo esta Perfecto en el funcionamiento.
¿Qué es lo que no he logrado hacer?
Que independiente todo lo anterior que funciona bien, esta imagen espejo tenga un "onclick" el cual al ser presionado, reste la cantidad al total. Es decir, el total por ejemplo va en 55, luego presiono "+10", llega a 65, pero me arrepiento de esa opción, entonces presiono en la imagen espejo y el total vuelva a 55.

En teoría, se que debe ser un atributo dinámico, el cual a través de una función, cambie el atributo "onclick" del botón espejo, a restar 5 o 10, según cual fue la última opción seleccionada.

Probablemente deba crear una línea adicional en cada uno de las funciones de los botones +5 y +10. el cual adicional a cambiar la imagen del botón espejo (eso funciona bien), modifique el atributo "onclick" de ella y pueda restar 5 o 10 según cual está visible en dicho espejo. Y bueno claramente faltaría la funcion "restar()" por cada opción que no está creada ya que sinceramente nada me funcionó.

Espero de su ayuda en caso sea posible esto que necesito.

Muchas e infinitas gracias por su ayuda de antemano. Aquí el código completo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function sumar() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".monto").each(function() {
//    $
    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {
      total += 0;
    } else {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
  });
  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
}
var count = 0
function funcion() {
  count++
  document.getElementById('bt').value = 10 * count
  sumar()
  document.getElementById("reset").src="https://icon-library.com/images/number-10-icon/number-10-icon-0.jpg";
}

var count2 = 0
function funcion2() {
  count2++
  document.getElementById('bt2').value = 5 * count2
  sumar()
  document.getElementById("reset").src="https://icon-library.com/images/5-icon/5-icon-6.jpg";
}


function resetear() {
  document.getElementById("spTotal").innerHTML = "0"
  count = 0;
  count2 = 0;
  document.getElementById('bt').value = 0;
  document.getElementById('bt2').value = 0;
  document.getElementById("reset").src="https://icon-library.com/images/loading-icon-png/loading-icon-png-7.jpg";
}

</script>

</head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>TOTAL:</td>
        <td><span id="spTotal">0</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <button class="monto" id="bt" onClick="funcion();">
      <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/number-10-icon/number-10-icon-0.jpg" width="50" height="50" />+ 10
    </button>
    
        <button class="monto" id="bt2" onClick="funcion2();">
      <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/5-icon/5-icon-6.jpg" width="50" height="50" /> + 5
    </button>
    <br>
    <br>

<button onclick="resetear()" class="button">CLEAR</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <p>Imagen espejo a la opción seleccionada. Vuelve a su estado original al dar "CLEAR"</p>
  

    <img src="https://icon-library.com/images/loading-icon-png/loading-icon-png-7.jpg" 
        style="" id="reset" onclick="" width="50px" height="50px"/>
  
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Prueba con: `elemento.onclick = funcion`. Aunque también podrías usar un `elemento.addEventListener("click", funcion)` o incluso guardar en una variable la última cantidad aumentada y en el evento `click` hacer que se reste dicha cantidad.

Comment: Por cierto, es recomendable que guardes los elementos en una variable en lugar de estar a cada rato llamando a `getElementById` o similares. También deberías saber que `var` sirve para declarar variables globales y `let` locales. Dependiendo de lo que quieras lograr usarás una u otra.

Comment: :o si! mañana probaré esa solución a ver como me va! soy nuevo y hay muchos conceptos que aun no manejo y claramente me pasa mucho que logro resultados pero no de la forma mas pulcra posible. Gracias por tu comentario mañana probare :D